# Angular - ngfor over map keyvalue

Tags: angular

I'm having issues with a Map in Angular. When I console.log the first item I get the things I expect (see screenshot), however using *NgFor I'm not getting results. I've tried a lot of things and currently have this HTML. The only thing that gives me the correct value is the .length

The last thing I found on the internet was the |json pipe, and that results in **"{ "key": "0", "value": {} }"**
Any ideas?

```
<div class="card card-default bg-secondary mb-3" *ngFor='let fiets of fietsen | keyvalue'>
        <div class="card-header">
            {{fiets | json }}
            {{fiets}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
                Merk: {{fiets.key}}  
                <br>Frame Hoogte: {{fiets.key}} cm
                <br>Model: {{fiets.key}} 
                <br> {{fiets.value}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">Totally a button</div>
</div>
```

[Console.log output (console.log(this._fietsen[0]);)][1]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have an array of objects and you want the objects key/value...
In this case you need another ngFor to loop the object after looping the array.

[angular.io example](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
<div class="card card-default bg-secondary mb-3" *ngFor='let fiets of fietsen '>
<div *ngFor="let obj of fiets | keyvalue">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{obj | json }}
        {{obj}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
            Merk: {{obj.key}}  
            <br>Frame Hoogte: {{obj.key}} cm
            <br>Model: {{obj.key}} 
            <br> {{obj.value}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">Totally a button</div>
```

Comment: That code helps me out a lot, thanks! :D

I had tried a second ngFor before, but I did keyvalue twice.... that was my issue oops

Would upvote but I'm not allowed to